# Error 401 when trying to register a new user. Works fine on localhost (Django rest api)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have built a rest API using Django. I have tested the endpoints and everything seems to be working fine on localhost.However after deploying to digital ocean and trying to access the endpoint to register a new user. I get Error 401. What could be the problem?

Comment: That you are unauthorized to do so. Note that your users/tokens on the test database, might not be the same on production.

Comment: how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a long shot, but I've had similar issues happen to me if I used HTTP when calling the URLs instead of HTTPS and/or forgetting to call routes with the slash at the end. What would end up happening is that the request would drop the token data for some reason.